# JIRA Log work with groovy script issue

Tags: groovy, jira, jira-plugin

Here is a code:

```
CM = ComponentManager.getInstance()
worklogManager = CM.getWorklogManager()

for(int i=0; i<=4; i++) {
    worklog = new WorklogImpl(worklogManager, issue, null, issue.reporter.name, issue.summary, new Date(), null, null, 1*3600)
    worklogManager.create(issue.reporter, worklog, 0L, false)
}
```

**OR**

```
for(int i=0; i<=4; i++) {
    params = WorklogInputParametersImpl
        .issue( issue )
        .startDate(new Date())
        .timeSpent('1h')
        .comment('123')
        .buildNewEstimate()

    result = wls.validateCreate(context, params)
    wls.createAndAutoAdjustRemainingEstimate(context, result, true)
}
```

And here is a result:

5 worklog entries, with 1 hour spent
but Logged: shows only 1 hour instead of 5 hours

latest script runner addon with JIRA 6.1
same results with JIRA 5.1.7

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Sergey

[image]

Comment: You're calling `.buildNewEstimate()` but is there a method to call to re-calculate the total spent hours?

Comment: @BorislavSabev I don't think so https://developer.atlassian.com/static/javadoc/jira/6.0/reference/com/atlassian/jira/bc/issue/worklog/WorklogInputParametersImpl.Builder.html#buildNewEstimate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to calculate logged time manually:

```
for(int i=0; i=4; i++) {
    worklog = new WorklogImpl(
        worklogManager,
        issue,
        null,
        issue.reporter.name,
        issue.summary,
        new Date(),
        null,
        null,
        1*3600
    )
    worklogManager.create(issue.reporter, worklog, 0L, false)
    issue.timeSpent = issue.timeSpent == null 
        ? 1*3600 
        : issue.timeSpent + 1*3600
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, solved it by changing the last parameter to `true` in `worklogManager.create()`. It dispatches the ISSUE_WORKLOGGED_ID event which I think is needed for the correct behaviour.